# VUE emit from child to parent v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props, emit

**child**

```js
template: `
    <li v-for="option in listaOptiuni" :key="option.id">
        <input @change="updateSelectAllToateOptiunile(); sendListaToateOptiunile()" v-model="listaToateOptiunile" :value="option" :id="option" type="checkbox" class="uk-checkbox">
        <label :for="option">{{ option.denumire }}</label>
    </li>
`

data: function() {
    return {
        listaToateOptiunile: []
    }
}
```

**parent**

```html
<my-component v-model="myList"></my-component>
```

How I send values of **listaToateOptiunile** from child direct into v-model **myList** from parent?

Answer (score 1):

By emitting the event `v-model` listens to.

In Vue2, that's `input`:

```
<input @change="updateSelectAllToateOptiunile(); sendListaToateOptiunile(), $emit('input', listaToateOptiunile)" v-model="listaToateOptiunile" :value="option" :id="option" type="checkbox" class="uk-checkbox">
```

In Vue 3, that's `update:modelValue`:

```
<input @change="updateSelectAllToateOptiunile(); sendListaToateOptiunile(), $emit('update:modelValue', listaToateOptiunile)" v-model="listaToateOptiunile" :value="option" :id="option" type="checkbox" class="uk-checkbox">
```